# Dependent or Prerequisite test step in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

[image: Test Suite structure]

I have following test suite in SoapUI and I want to add Test_case_1-Step_2 as a prerequisite for test step Test_case_2-Step_2.

How may I achieved this in SoapUI GUI?

Also
How may I add Test_case_2-Step_1 to run before and Test_case_2-Step_3 to run after Test_case_2-Step_2?

Comment: You can do it by calling the tests from a Groovy script. Then you can build any logic that you want into the Groovy script.

Comment: is there any way to achieve it without script?

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI has the [Run TestCase TestStep](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/modularizing-your-tests/), which you could use.

Add the step to the beginning of your "Test_case_2-Step_2", and point it at your "Test_case_1-Step_2".

More detailed information is available in the [ReadyAPI documentation](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/functional/steps/run-test-case.html), which ports over to SoapUI.